# Why getting item from vec creates NullPointerException in Clojure and Play-clj

Tags: clojure, play-clj

I am creating a simple worm game in play-clj.

I have a function that should return a vec with dedicated number of new texture object added. It takes the place of coordinate in list and list as arguments. But every time I pass a number greater than 3 to that function it gives me `NullPointerException`.

The function is called from render function. Lastx and lasty are both vectors of the last location of my worms head.
Here's my code:

```
(defn getCoords [list many]
  (nth (into [] (reverse list)) 
       (- many 1)))


(defn getParts[entities many]
  (clojure.set/union
   (vec (for [i (range 1 many)] 
          (assoc (texture "part.png") :height 30 :width 30
                 :x (getCoords (get (first entities) :lastx) i)
                 :y (getCoords (get (first entities) :lasty) i))))
   entities))

;; and this calls it 
(render! screen (getParts entities 4 ))
```

This is contents of entities

```
[(assoc (texture "part.png") :x 30 :y 30 :direction 2 :dead 1 :height 30 :width 30:score 4 :lastx [] :lasty[]) 
 (assoc (texture "text.png") :width 200 :height 0 :x  (- (/ (game :width) 2) 40) :y (/ (game :height) 2))
 (assoc (texture "food.png") :height 0 :x (*(rand-int 25) 30) :y (*(rand-int 19) 30))]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to put more details in the question. Like what is `texture` or contents of "part.png", or `entities`

Comment: Texture is texture of play-clj. Added now content of entities